# Showing error message when I'm trying to update - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I'm new in Laravel. I attached my code whenever I update the form it gives same error. Please check my code throughly and let me know where is the error.

```
public function updateCategory(Request $request) {

        $catname = $request->catname;
        if($catimg = $request->hasFile('updatecatimg')) {

            File::cleanDirectory(public_path().'/images/'.$catname);

            $catimg = $request->file('updatecatimg');
            $catimgnm = $catimg->getClientOriginalName();
            $storeTo = public_path() . '/images/' . $catname;
            File::makeDirectory($storeTo, $mode = 0777, true, true);
            $catimg->move($storeTo, $catimgnm);
        }

        Category::where('cat_id', $request->catid)->update(['cat_name' => $catname, 'cat_img' => $catimgnm, 'status' => $request->status]);

        return back();
    }
```

Category Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AddCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cms_category';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';
}
```

Folder
[image]

DB
[image]

[image]

Error
[image]

please help me...

Comment: Try printing $catimgnm variable first using error_log($catimgnm) or dd($catimgnm). Could you please share us your blade file also? I think I know your problem but I need to make sure first.

Comment: `$catimgnm` is only set `if($catimg = $request->hasFile('updatecatimg')) {`

Comment: just post the snippet for your image input

Comment: @KevinYobeth give your email id

Comment: <form action="{{ url('/updatecategory').'/'.$cat->cat_id }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="custom-file">
                                      <input type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpg,image/jpeg" class="custom-file-input" name="updatecatimg">
                                      <label class="custom-file-label" for="catimg">Choose file</label>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                  </div>

Comment: <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                                </div>
                              </form>

Comment: @KevinYobeth please check once

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67698044/after-login-how-to-show-user-details-in-blade-page-laravel-5-8

please check this link I need help @KevinYobeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated answer. `Category::findOrFail()` will find the category object, using it, we can update specific field only and use `save()` function to update the object.

```
  public function updateCategory(Request $request)
  {
    $catId = $request->catid;
    $category = Category::findOrFail($catId);
    $oldCategory = $category->cat_name;
    rename(public_path() . '/images/' . $oldCategory, public_path() . '/images/' . $request->catname);

    $category->cat_name = $request->catname;

    if ($request->hasFile('updatecatimg')) {

      File::cleanDirectory(public_path() . '/images/' . $request->catname);

      $catImg = $request->file('updatecatimg');
      $category->cat_img = $catImg->getClientOriginalName();

      $storeTo = public_path() . '/images/' . $request->catname;
      File::makeDirectory($storeTo, $mode = 0777, true, true);
      $catImg->move($storeTo, $request->catname);
    }

    $category->save();

    return back();
  }
```

Comment: But If I'm trying to update title only not the old image it update but it cannot save the updated content....

Comment: I add that line above the if statement. But I want to know if I'm trying to update title only it didn't save but If I'm update the title and image both then works. Why? Please help

Comment: In that case, you could just update what you need. I have updated the code according to your needs, it should work. It checks if there is `updatecatimg` file attached, it there is, it will update all fields. If there is not, it will only update the `cat_name` and return back. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please write the code so that I can understand it....

Comment: I have check it and it works fine but if I'm update only title the image is gone and shows a broken link shows on my listing page....

Comment: WHen I'm uploading category name and image, cat name save as folder name but when I'm trying to update category name it update and store in DB but the folder name is cannot be renamed with that updated name that's why the image is not showing.....

Comment: pls help me out

Comment: Please add your `Category` model on your post

Comment: namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AddCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cms_category';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';
}

Comment: List all of your `Category` database's attributes also, and please use edit on your post, don't post it all on comments.

Comment: I have added the Model Code as well as DB screenshot

Comment: I just want that whenever I update the title, the folder name has also change but it's not happening....

Comment: Please check the folder name and the category name both are same but whenever I upadte it the db updates but the folder name remain same.

Comment: So you also want to change the folder name when updating just the title?

Comment: That should do it

Comment: Please check I have add the error page screenshot. Got error with that code @Kevin Yobeth

Comment: Please try it again

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother. You help me a lot. Do you have any idea regarding this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67469793/how-will-i-set-seo-friendly-url-in-custom-php

@Kevin Yobeth

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code.

This is your edit file

```
  <input type="hidden" name="old_image" id="old_image"
     value="{{isset($contact->cat_img)?$contact->cat_img:''}}">
```

After:

```
use File;

 public function updateCategory(Request $request) {

   if ($request->hasFile('updatecatimg')){
     $image_path = public_path('/images/'.$request->old_image);
       if(File::exists($image_path)){
          unlink($image_path);
       } 

       $file = $request->file('updatecatimg');
       $catimgnm  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $destinationPath = public_path('/images/');
       $file->move($destinationPath, $catimgnm  );
       $contact = "YOUR MODEL NAME"::find($request->cat_id);
       $contact->cat_img =$catimgnm ;
       $contact->save();    
  }
}
```

I hope this code is working in your Controllers.

Comment: unlink(D:\xampp\htdocs\Office\VTPL\Varneli HOME_CMS\vareliCMS\public\/images/): Is a directory

Comment: $contact = Category::find($request->cat_id); shows NULL return

Comment: @AbhijitDutta  You shud enter your file, add this line anywhere.

 <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" id="cat_id" value="{{isset($contact->id)?$contact->id:''}}" />

This line is requested for your database image row id.

Comment: @AbhijitDutta Can you give me your edit file code, controller code, and error screen short?. so I can understand what is exactly the problem in your code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ltZ2cxr6r6xvAIqyqs3O7FIHPS-tt-z8?usp=sharing

Comment: Please check the GDRIVE all the files are uploaded and DB screenshot is here