# After login how to show user details in blade page Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I want to check user type and show the names on the blade page. Here is the database

[image]

I want if type_user = 1 and validate with Auth:check id then print VTPL Administration, then type_user = 2 & 3

How will I check it in blade page.

here is the blade page

[image]

Here is my User Model

[image]

Error

[image]

Controller code

[image]

Please help me....

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (Auth::check())
    <p> {{Auth::User()->type_user == 1 ? Auth::User()->name : ""}} </p> 
@endif
```

Just,use Ternary Operator according to Condition.

changes according to your field in  Controller Code

```
public function authCheck() {
    $input = Request::all();
    $rule = array(
        'email' => 'required|exists:users',
        'password' => 'required'
    );
    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rule, array());
    if ($validation->fails()) {
        $messages = $validation->errors();
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($messages);
    }
    $cred = [
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'password' => $input['password'],
    ];
    Auth::attempt($cred, true);
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user_type = Auth::User()->type_user;
        if ($user_type == 1) {
            return redirect()->to('/adminlogin');
        } else {
            return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
        }
    } else {
        $message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('error', $message);
    }
}
```

changes in your  Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class AdminUserLogin extends Authenticatable {
    
    use Notifiable;
   
protected $table = 'user';
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'status',
    'type_user',
];
protected $casts = [
    'type_user' => 'integer',
    'status' => 'integer',
];
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];}
```

Hope fully it will help to you easily.

Comment: what's getting in Auth::check() ?

Comment: if you are login then it's work, because it works perfectly from my side.

Comment: It returns nothing.... Whenever I put a div under @if (Auth::check())
the div is disappear that means the function is not working
Is it working with Laravel 8

Comment: check this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication

Comment: I already checked and done that way but it's not working....

Comment: Okay then check your User Model and also check in the controller file after login, what's getting in Auth::check()?

Comment: I have no User model, my model name is AdminUserLogin....

Comment: I have attached my User model

Comment: public function authCheck(Request $request) {

        $ademail = $request->ademail;
        $adpwd = $request->adpwd;

        $request->session()->put('ademail', $ademail);
        $getlogin = Userlog::where('email', $ademail)
                    ->where('password', $adpwd)
                    ->get();

        if(count($getlogin) == 1) {
            
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        else {
            
            return redirect('/adminlogin')->with(Session::flash('message', 'Login Credential is incorrect'));
        }
    }

Comment: okay, first check login successfully or not.

Comment: Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically

I got this error

Comment: so first complete login flow and then after login successfully check it.

Comment: Using my code login is works perfectly but whenever I replace my code with your then the login is not working...

Comment: what's an error in the above login method?

Comment: Whenever I enter wrong email/password it shows noting, whenever I used same email/password which was saved in db it also shows noting and cannot enter the dashboard page. I just want in blade page after login just want to show user name...
My user table name is ADMINUSER.

Comment: sorry, not getting your point, what's an issue from your side.check it login example.

Comment: I used DB saved correct email and password sit shows nothing, it just reload the page and if I used wrong password it shows the same.

Comment: Is it easier for you if I provide you all files?

Answer (score 0):

```
@dump(Auth::user()->type_user);
```

```
@if (Auth::check())
<div class="info">
   <a class="d-block">{{ Auth::user()->name ?? ""}}</a>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: I didn't understand your reply bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an append field `type_user_name` and `getTypeUserName` [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) in your `App/Models/User` Model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $appends = ['type_user_name'];

    public function getTypeUserNameAttribute()
    {
        $type_user = $this->attributes['type_user'];
        
        if ($type_user == 1) return "VTPL Administration";
        if ($type_user == 2) return "User 2";
        if ($type_user == 3) return "User 3";
    }

}
```

So whenever you will query `auth()->user()`, you will get `type_user_name` field populated.

Comment: It's already mentioned in database I just want after login to check Auth:check () with type_user then show name. That's it.

Comment: I have attached the user model is it ok now? please check it

Comment: @AbhijitDutta did you try the above code ?

Comment: It doesn't work. I add that code but It's doesn't work